# React native elements search bar on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

when im typing on the search bar and press submit the flatlist should render again making an api request but it doesnt
The method makeRequest is not called in updateSearch and i dont know why

```
 <SearchBar
     placeholder="Type something here...."
     onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
     value={search}
 />

updateSearch = search => {
    this.setState({ search }, this.makeRequest);    
  };

makeRequest =  () => {

    const { page, search } = this.state;

    const apiKey = 'a40093f0-53ec-11ea-850a-fbf5bb8990e'

    const url =
            `https://api.harvardartmuseums.org/object?apikey=${apiKey}` +
            `&title=${search}`+
            `&fields=objectnumber,dated,century,division,primaryimageurl,title` +
            `&sort=totalpageviews` +
            `&page=${page}` +
            `&size=44` +
            `&hasimage=1` +
            `&sortorder=desc`;
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        const results = processExhibit(responseJson);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: [...this.state.dataSource,...results],
          refreshing: false
        });

      });
    }, 1500);

  }
```

https://snack.expo.io/@overhype/885549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try with below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Card, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

const apiKey = 'a40093f0-53ec-11ea-850a-fbf5bb8990ef';

 const processExhibit = results => {
  const processed = 
    results.records.map(r => ({
      ...r,
      id: r.objectnumber
    }))
  return processed;
};

export default class FetchExample extends Component {

  constructor (props: {}) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        page: 1,
        isLoading: true,
        dataSource: [],
        refreshing: false,
        search: 'cat'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.makeRequest();
  }

  makeRequest =  () => {

    const { page, search } = this.state;
    const url =
            `https://api.harvardartmuseums.org/object?apikey=${apiKey}` +
            `&title=${search}`+
            `&fields=objectnumber,dated,century,division,primaryimageurl,title` +
            `&sort=totalpageviews` +
            `&page=${page}` +
            `&size=44` +
            `&hasimage=1` +
            `&sortorder=desc`;
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        const results = processExhibit(responseJson);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: results,
          refreshing: false
        });

      });
    }, 1500);
  }

  renderItem = ({item, index}) => {

    if (!item) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <View >
        <Card
          title={item.title}
          image={{uri: item.primaryimageurl}}>
          <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
            Made in {item.dated}
          </Text>
       </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
    return index.toString();
  }

  updateSearch = search => {
    this.setState({ search });  
    this.makeRequest(search);
  };

  handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1}, this.makeRequest)
  }

  handleRefresh = () => {

    this.setState({
      page: 1,
      refreshing: true,

    }),
    () =>
      this.makeRequest();
  }

  render () {
    const { search } = this.state;
    return (

      <View style={{flex: 1}}>

        <SearchBar
            placeholder="Type something here...."
            onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
            value={search}
        />
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          onEndThreshold={100}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Snack : https://snack.expo.io/Sk!aRjR78

Comment: While this could work it changes the behavior OP wants by setting state after succession

Comment: i tried that but nothing happens, here's the snack : https://snack.expo.io/@overhype/885549

Comment: do you want to make a request everytime the user types?

Comment: I think it wouldve been best if the user finishes typing then make the request but i didnt know how

Comment: Hi @GherghinaAndrei check now: https://snack.expo.io/@overhype/885549 And there is a state clearing issue also there

Comment: If u can show me where i will fix it, im new to react native

Comment: @GherghinaAndrei please check now it also fixed: snack: https://snack.expo.io/@overhype/885549

Comment: The feed still doesnt refresh

Comment: @GherghinaAndrei sorry I send wrong snack check this : https://snack.expo.io/Sk!aRjR78

Comment: Thank you!! you can post it as an answer so i can accept the answer

Comment: @GherghinaAndrei done; You can accept it now 

Answer (score 6):

to avoid repeatly call API when user typing, using onSubmitEditing which fired when user click submit on soft keyboard

```
const [keywords, setKeywords] = React.useState('')

<Searchbar
  placeholder="Search Products ..." 
  onChangeText={(val) => { setKeywords(val) }}
  onSubmitEditing={()=>console.log(`User typed ${keywords}`)}
  value={keywords} 
/>
```

or replaced with

```
onSubmitEditing={({nativeEvent})=>console.log(nativeEvent.text)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `setTimeout` as it might show results that are not related to what the user has typed. if you want to make a request with each key press just call `makeRequest` in `updateSearch`. Try adding min character length to minimise making requests with each key press.

```
updateSearch = search => {
  this.setState({ search }, () => this.makeRequest());
};

makeRequest = () => {
  const { page, search, minLength } = this.state;

  if (search && search.length < minLength) {
    return;
  }

  const url =
    `https://api.harvardartmuseums.org/object?apikey=${apiKey}` +
    `&title=${search}` +
    `&fields=objectnumber,dated,century,division,primaryimageurl,title` +
    `&sort=totalpageviews` +
    `&page=${page}` +
    `&size=44` +
    `&hasimage=1` +
    `&sortorder=desc`;

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      console.log(responseJson);
      const results = processExhibit(responseJson);
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: [...this.state.dataSource, ...results],
        refreshing: false,
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: im trying now to make the request after the user finished typing, thank you for the suggestion!